# What is the tension in a section of a bar?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

suppose you have a homogenous bar AB and two forces that act at each end of the bar. given the bar's mass and length, the value of the forces and the coefficient of friction, how can you find the tension in a section of the bar?